# Google Map Api v2 shows the local module descriptor class is not found

Tags: android, api, google-maps, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

I met this issue today once I started application on my emulator but everything is right yesterday, I haven't edited any changes on the day before. Also the API key is valid after investigating.

Things I've tried:

1. Downgrading the version of com.google.android.gms services
2. updating all of services to the latest version
3. rebuild/clean project
4. Invalidate/Restart the Android Studio

but the error still exists.

The Logcat shows when the emulator turned on the application:

```
09-20 09:49:09.261 25985-25985/com.abc.abc I/c: Token loaded from file. Expires in: 174900321 ms.
09-20 09:49:11.339 25985-26088/com.abc.abc W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not found.
09-20 09:49:11.341 25985-26088/com.abc.abc I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:1
09-20 09:49:11.341 25985-26088/com.abc.abc I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates, version >= 1
09-20 09:49:11.343 25985-26088/com.abc.abc D/GoogleCertificates: com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates module is loaded
```

My build.grade(Module:app) compiled those services on my application:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
    compile 'me.angrybyte.picker:picker:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.2.1'
}
```

I found someone who met this problem and ask on this site but I am not sure where the error is caused on my application. Thank you.

UPDATED:
The google map can shows but I cannot be gathered the data of console.log(country code/country name) by clicking the map (onClick function).

Comment: Can you post the whole error that you got. And the code that you use for this.

Comment: @KENdi The whole error I got as the same of above......

Comment: I no longer getting the errors yesterday but seldom will meet today, I just puzzled.